# Distribution of colour pairs from a random matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, enumerative-combinatorics

Given $a$ many red balls and $b$ many blue balls, with $a+b$ even, suppose we chose a random matching between the $a+b$ balls. What is the distribution of the number of red-red and red-blue (and blue-blue) pairs?

I can write down an easy recurrence relation, saying $p(x, y, z | a, b)$ is the probability that we have x many red-red pairs, y many red-blue and z many blue-blue, provided that we started with a red and b blue. Assuming $a \leq b$ then $$p(x, y, z | a, b) = \frac{a-1}{a+b-1} p(x-1, y, z | a-2, b) + \frac{b}{a+b-1} p(x, y-1, z | a-1, b-1)$$ with initial values
$$p(x, y, z | 0, 2z) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x=y=0 \\ \newline 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ and $$p(x, y, z| 1, 2z+1) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x=0, y=1 \\ \newline 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}.$$ I wonder if there is a better way to calculate these, in particular if there is an easy way to find the asymptotic behaviour of the probabilities.

There are numerous variants of the question. The simplest is extending it to more colours. For a single colour pair's distribution, I can see that it is enough to generalise it to 3 colours, since it is always possible to group the rest of the colours together (for example with colours RGBY, getting the R-Y pair's distribution is the same, even if we assume G and B is the same colour). For the joint distributions it is relevant that there are more colours though.

It is also interesting to ask asymptotic bounds on probabilities of common events. Like for some $\alpha : \beta : \gamma$ ratio, we have $\alpha n, \beta n, \gamma n$ many RGB balls, what is the asymptotic probability that there is no R-G pair? The possible questions are endless.

Another variant is where the partition is already provided. Here we have $a_1$ red, $b_1$ blue in the first partition and $a_2$ red, $b_2$ blue in the second partition, with $a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2$. If we chose a random matching between the parts, what is the distribution of the pairs?

If this was investigated before, any reference would be welcome!

Comment: I think the calculation is quite straightforward. The number of matchings with $x$ red-red pairs seems to be $a!*b!/(2^{x+z}*x!*y!*z!)$, where $y=a-2x$ and $z=(b-a+2x)/2$.